# Spark Caching - data distribution and replication

Tags: apache-spark

How does spark decide how many times to replicate a cached partition? The storage level in the storage tab on the spark UI says “Disk Serialized 1x Replicated”, but it looks like partitions get replicated onto multiple executors. We have noticed this happening with both DISK_ONLY and OFF_HEAP storage levels using spark 2.3. We are caching a dataset with 101 partitions (size on disk is 468.4 GB). Data is distributed initially on 101 executors (we have 600 executors total). As we run queries on this dataset, the size on disk grows as well as the number of executors data is distributed on.

When I am running spark query on the cached dataset , then i can see the spark job is creating 101 task and assigning it to 101 executors.
Few of the executors are PROCESS_LOCAL and few other are NODE_LOCAL or RACK_LOCAL.
For the NODE_LOCAL and RACK_LOCAL , task execution taking longer time as it involves data copying.

I have notice that, on each query execution if the task is assigned on NODE_LOCAL or RACK_LOCAL then
the cache size is increasing.At one stage I have seen it to crossed 2.5TB

I want to understand why the cache size is increasing upon query execution?
If this is the default spark behavior as its copy data from DISK to NODE_LOCAL or RACK_LOCAL executor, then how to manage the cache size?

I also noticed that commonly one block/partition is replicated on multiple executors on the same node – if it is stored on disk, why is this not shared between executors of same node?

Comment: What is `spark.locality.wait` set to? Is it possible for you to increase this value to say, a minute or two and see if disk usage profile improves.

Comment: its the default 3 seconds

Comment: If I set spark.locality.wait to a higher value then, it will impact all query execution in my application. I am looking for the reason behind following spark behavior 
- why cache size is constantly increasing when the cached dataset is accessed and how to manage it ?
- why spark is not honoring the replication factor which is set 1 by default ?
-  one block/partition is replicated on multiple executors on the same node : if it is stored on disk, why is this not shared between executors of same node?